# Mass Send email with list/table of data

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, massemailmessage

I would like to send an email to 500 Person Accounts every day. The email contains a personalised list of their appointments for the day.

What is the best approach for achieving this using Salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a scheduled job to run a batchable job to send out the emails. That would look like this:

```
public class DailyReminders implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<Sobject> {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    Database.executeBatch(this, 100);
  }
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
      SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsPersonAccount = TRUE
    ]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    Messaging.Email[] emails = new Messaging.Email[0];
    EmailTemplate t = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'some template'];
    ...
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
  }
  ...
}
```

Depending on how many queries you need, you may need to adjust the batch size (100 is depicted here) to avoid governor limits.

Comment: How would I populate the table/list of appointments in the email?

Comment: @Robs I thought you had a Visualforce template that did that? Or have you not gotten that far yet?

Comment: I haven't got that far, because I am not sure how I would display a different list of appointments in each email without hitting a SOQL govenor limit?

Comment: @Robs If you're using a template, you do need (at least) one query per person. As I stated, you will need to adjust the batch size to the appropriate value to get the desired output.

Comment: What other options do I have? i.e. how would it work without a template?

Comment: @Robs generate the text dynamically in Apex.

Comment: I was worried you'd say that...

Comment: @Robs as I said, you could use a Visualforce template, just keep the batch size smaller. Even a batch size of just 25 would still give you just 20 executions (should take less than a minute).